# How can I expand the option without using the arrow button in antd select?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I would like to know if this is possible in antd tree select. As you can see in the image. How can I expand the option without using the arrow button? I just want to click the word "Expand to load" and then drop down options will show.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was playing around with their code in codesandbox.io.

This is what I came up with: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-frog-pr1qu?file=/index.js

You'll have to create a `span` node when populating the `title` of your tree elements, where the `span` elements will listen for a click event.

```js
  const treeData = [
    {
      title: <span onClick={() => expandNode("0-0")}>0-0</span>,
      key: "0-0",
      children: [
        {
          title: <span onClick={() => expandNode("0-0-0")}>0-0-0</span>,
          key: "0-0-0",
          children: [
            {
              title: "0-0-0-0",
              key: "0-0-0-0"
            },
            {
              title: "0-0-0-1",
              key: "0-0-0-1"
            },
            {
              title: "0-0-0-2",
              key: "0-0-0-2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: <span onClick={() => expandNode("0-0-1")}>0-0-1</span>,
          key: "0-0-1",
          children: [
            {
              title: "0-0-1-0",
              key: "0-0-1-0"
            },
            {
              title: "0-0-1-1",
              key: "0-0-1-1"
            },
            {
              title: "0-0-1-2",
              key: "0-0-1-2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "0-0-2",
          key: "0-0-2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: <span onClick={() => expandNode("0-1")}>0-1</span>,
      key: "0-1",
      children: [
        {
          title: "0-1-0-0",
          key: "0-1-0-0"
        },
        {
          title: "0-1-0-1",
          key: "0-1-0-1"
        },
        {
          title: "0-1-0-2",
          key: "0-1-0-2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "0-2",
      key: "0-2"
    }
  ];
```

Then use a custom function to set the expandedKeys state and pass it as a prop to the Tree component. I tried using the `filter` method on the previous state for removing keys but it kept giving me an error so I fell back to using the `for` loop.

```js
  const expandNode = (key) => {
    setAutoExpandParent(false);
    setExpandedKeys((prev) => {
      const outArr = [];
      if (prev.includes(key)) {
        for (let i = 0; i < prev.length; i++) {
          if (prev[i] !== key) {
            outArr.push(prev[i]);
          }
        }
        return outArr;
      } else {
        prev.push(key);
        return prev;
      }
    });
  };
```

Note: I used antd's "Controlled Tree" example as the template and progressed from there.

---

**Update**

As I was using this solution for a project of mine, I found out a more robust method.

1. Instead of individually overriding the `title` properties on the data array, it is possible to override the `titleRender` prop on the tree component. `titleRender` is available from antd v.4.5.0.
2. Style the `span` tags as `inline-block` with width and height set to 100%. This makes the entire node block (instead of just the span text) listen for the `onClick` event when the tree has a prop of `blockNode={true}`.
3. Got rid of the `for` loop and successfully used `filter` method instead in the toggle expand method. This is more performant than looping.

I created a custom `ClickExpandableTree` component.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Tree } from "antd";

const ClickExpandableTree = props => {
  const [expandedKeys, setExpandedKeys] = useState([]);
  const [autoExpandParent, setAutoExpandParent] = useState(true);

  const toggleExpandNode = key => {
    setExpandedKeys(prev => {
      const outArr = [...prev];
      if (outArr.includes(key)) {
        return outArr.filter(e => e !== key);
      } else {
        outArr.push(key);
        return outArr;
      }
    });
    setAutoExpandParent(false);
  };

  const onExpand = keys => {
    setExpandedKeys(keys);
    setAutoExpandParent(false);
  };

  return (
    <Tree
      onExpand={onExpand}
      expandedKeys={expandedKeys}
      autoExpandParent={autoExpandParent}
      titleRender={record => (
        <span
          key={record.key}
          onClick={() => toggleExpandNode(record.key)}
          style={{ display: "inline-block", width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
        >
          {record.title}
        </span>
      )}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};

export default ClickExpandableTree;
```